# How do I use embedded HTML form data when method is POST?

Tags: html, forms, perl, post, get

I have an assignment for school. We need to use the POST method to pass data from an embedded HTML form to a Perl script. The Perl will then loop through the data and display it back to the user.

I was using a separate file and the GET method but my instructor said I had to embed the HTML and use POST. But the information is no longer stored in the environment variable.

Is there a built-in variable I can use to access this information?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print "Content-Type:text/html\n\n";

$qstring = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
$rmethod = $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'};

if ( $rmethod eq "GET" ) {
    &displayform();
}
elsif ( $rmethod eq "POST" ) {

    @pairs = split(/&/, $qstring);

    foreach (@pairs) {
        ($key, $value) = split(/=/);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $form{$key} = $value;
    }

    print "<html><head><title>Student Survey</title></head>\n";
    print "<body>\n";

    &displayInfo();

    print "</body></html>\n";
}

print "</body></html>\n";
}

sub displayInfo {
    print "Full Name:",        $form{"person"}, "<br>";
    print "Favourite:",        $form{"sport"},  "<br>";
    print "Favourite Course:", $form{"course"}, "<br>";
    print "GPA:",              $form{"gpa"},    "<br>";
}

sub displayform {
    print qq~ (FORM GOES HERE)
```

Comment: Considering this is for a school assignment, you're going to need to show a significant amount of effort. Could you please update your question to show [**what you have already tried**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) with regards to the new approach, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My issue I believe resides in the environment variable since testing I have not been able to find a way to pull the form elements. Edited to show my script so far.

Comment: Use [CGI::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Simple) instead of cargo-culted code from the last decade of the 20th century. Also, if this is what they are teaching you, ask for a refund.

Comment: I would assume that you're supposed to `use strict` and `use warnings` and indent your code properly? I've tidied the Perl that you've shown so that I could read it and it becomes immediately obvious that it won't even compile. We're not here to sort out your junk code. If you can't make an effort with what you write then I certainly won't fix it for you.

Comment: @Borodin Actually I have not missed any lectures and maintain a GPA of 4.0, but the class is being taught by a prof who has no prior knowledge of perl and cgi because the regular prof died. The course has been removed for students who started a semester after me, but all we have is a log book written 15 years ago by the prof who created the course. I have had to perform 3 lectures for the class now that I have learned more about perl from perlmonks. Thanks for your snarky reply though.

Comment: @KieranO'Connor: Note that your question got three downvotes (none of them mine) and my comment got an upvote. The best way to learn a language is to read the documentation and experiment with what you have read. If you want to ask a question then it should be oriented towards learning the language rather than getting an answer to your problem.

Comment: @Borodin It doesn't matter what you think, I have reported your comments. Best of luck with your endeavors.

Comment: @KieranO'Connor: All that reporting my comments may do is to get them deleted, which is an odd thing to want if you say it doesn't matter what I think. If you're passing on your knowledge then I hope you've started using `use strict` and stopped calling subroutines with an ampersand?

Comment: @Borodin: I'm pretty sure you misunderstood *the information is no longer stored in the environment variable*. I suspect it means "I can get the parameters from the environment variable for a GET request, but for a POST request, the data appears to be stored elsewhere - and I can't work out where". It sounds like this is a really badly-run course and I'm getting flashbacks to 1988 when I was being taught C by a lecturer who was reading K&R two chapters ahead of the class :-/

Comment: @DaveCross: Ah thank you, that helps. If this is with regard to the same course as his most recent question then it is being taken by a professor who doesn't know the subject based on some old notes from a different lecturer who has now passed away. I can understand that writing CGI code without using them module may be beneficial, but I don't like the insistence on embedding HTML in the source.

Comment: @DaveCross: Maybe you can help Kieran out with [today's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214778/) as he seems to approve of you!

Comment: @Borodin: I was just looking at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone is teaching you very bad practices. I don't know whether your sample code is following examples supplied by your school or whether you have cobbled it together from bad examples on the internet - but either way, this code uses techniques that have been out of date for twenty years.

There's a whole debate to be had about the wisdom of teaching CGI programming in 2017 (see [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for a brief discussion of some better approaches) but let's ignore that and assume that CGI is a good idea here.

If you're writing a CGI program, then you should use the [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) library which has been part of the standard Perl distribution for over twenty years (it was removed recently, but the chances of your school using a version this up to date is tiny).

A standard CGI program, using CGI.pm looks like this:

```
#!/user/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw[header param]; # Load the two functions we're going to use

# Display the content-type header
print header;

# See if we have been passed parameters.
if (param) {
  # Display the parameters
  # Note: I've ignored HTML here. You shouldn't
  print 'Name: ', param('person');
  print 'Sport: ', param('sport');
  # etc... 
} else {
  # Display the form
  ...
}
```

I ignored HTML in my example because embedding HTML in your Perl code is a terrible idea. It's a much better idea to use a templating system (I recommend the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template)).

A few other points:

- Always `use strict` and `use warnings`.
- `-w` on the shebang was obsoleted by `use warnings` in 2000.
- Using `&` on subroutine calls has been unnecessary since Perl 5 was released in 1994.

I know that you don't know any better and that you're just following what your teacher is telling you to do. But it's really depressing to see such outdated practices been taught in school.

**Update:** And just to add the answer to your original question. You're right that in a POST request, the parameter data is no longer available in the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable - you need to read it from `STDIN` instead. That's one of the many advantages of CGI.pm - you use the same method (the `param()` subroutine) to access both GET and POST parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I have already finished the assignment long ago, and built it the exact way you have showed. 
Yes the course is based on a prof who wrote it 15+ years ago and never changed anything.