# Using SFTP to transfer images from HTML form to remote linux server using PERL/CGI.pm

Tags: linux, bash, perl

This is a school project, and the instructor has no knowledge of how to write the code.

I am using [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) and I am attempting to transfer a file without using [`Net::FTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP) or [`Net::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP) since the server I am attempting to transfer it to will not allow connections from these services. I have written the HTML form and I am able to grab the name of the file uploaded through `CGI`.

Is it possible to use the SFTP command within a Perl script that resides on a Linux server using bash to transfer a file uploaded through an HTML form?

If anyone knows a way to do it please post the code so I can modify it and insert into my script.

Comment: You need to explain where you're moving your file from and to. There's CGI server, a system where the file is, and a system where you want to copy the file to. Are two of these system the same? I also don't understand why you want to use `SFTP` if the destination system won't accept it.

Comment: *"If anyone knows a way to do it please post the code so I can modify it and insert into my script"* That is not a good way to learn to program.

Comment: I am putting the file on the server which Apache and the cgi script resides. I was told by my professor it is impossible and nobody has updated the project in 20 years.

Comment: Right, so we're going to need some more information. You have a CGI program that uploads a file from the user's local machine to a web server. You then want to transfer that file to a different server. But you've been unsuccessful using Net::FTP or Net::SFTP. Is that accurate? It would be very helpful to know what that lack of success looked like. Did you get an error message? Did the file just not appear on the target server? Did your school's computer centre burst into flames?

Comment: Do you think that FTP is running on the target server? Do you have an FTP account on the server? Same questions for SFTP. You see, if (S)FTP isn't available on the target server, then it won't matter whether you're using a Perl module or the command-line program. If it doesn't work, then it doesn't work. But if you can get it working with the command-line program, then it should be possible to get it working through the equivalent Perl module.

Comment: Please clarify whether this is just a matter of needing one image file copied to the HTTP server (in which case perhaps you could just use a flash drive) or if you need to write some CGI code that will allow you to upload any file from the client machine to the host, for which you need only HTTP,. The whole process for the latter is described in the documentation for the `CGI` module under [*CREATING A FILE UPLOAD FIELD*](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm#CREATING_A_FILE_UPLOAD_FIELD). If it's a different scenario that I haven't thought of then you will have to explain.

Comment: In short, please edit your question to tell us **exactly** what you have tried and **exactly** what unexpected behaviour you are seeing and we might have a chance of getting this fixed for you. Without that information, we're all just wasting our time.

Comment: ...And do it soon. Your question already has three close votes :-)

Comment: Borodin thank you for providing the guide. I was not able to find information on uploading with Google, I have written my code and it works perfectly using -wT.
I appreciate the constructive criticism, however I already have employment where I will never be using perl. I am trying to get through the course with an instructor who can not provide instructions.

Comment: @KieranO'Connor: It sounds like you have solved your problem. If that's  the case, it would be a good idea to write up your solution as an answer to your question. You can even accept your own answer. Without an answer, this question is useless to anyone with a similar problem who comes across it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use File::Basename;
my ( $name, $path, $extension) = fileparse ( $productimage, '..*' ); 
$productimage = $name . $extension;
$productimage =~ tr/ /_/; $productimage =~ s/[^$safechars]//g;
if ( $productimage =~/^([$safechars]+)$/ ) {
    $productimage = $1;
} else {
    die "Filename contains invalid characters";
}

$fh = upload('image');
$uploaddir = "../../.hidden/images";
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$uploaddir/$productimage" )
  or die "$!"; binmode UPLOADFILE;

while (<$fh>) {
    print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;
```

This is the code I used to upload the file into the server.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code (and a couple of `Use` vs `use` typos). Please be more careful in the future.